# See historic connected clients on Cisco AP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have 4 Cisco Aironet 1130AG Series Access points, with a differing number of clients associated with them.

Is it possible to see clients whom are now disconnected from the AP, but were once connected?

i.e. Client 1 is connected to the AP, but fails, and no longer communicates with the AP. Is it possible to "see" this connection, as a device that was historically connected? Or is it only possible to see clients that have an active connection?

Answer (score 1):

"`show log`" will give you buffer log of Cisco AP, and it will list historical connection information if the level is set to debugging. Depending on activity, you may have to set the log size higher than default 4096 bytes. If you need to keep the data for extended period of time, or in case the AP is rebooted and you don't want loose the logs, you can setup a Syslog server to save these log entries on a Separate Server.